# Laravel Ajax get request 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to fetch a single row item using the id using an ajax call.

Route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('products.categories.index');
});

Route::resource('product-categories', 'ProductCategoriesController');
Route::get('product-categories/fetchdata', 'ProductCategoriesController@fetchdata')->name('category.fetchdata');
```

ProductCategoriesController:

```
    public function fetchdata(Request $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    $category = ProductCategory::find($id);
    $data = array(
        'name' => $category->name,
        'subcategory' => $category->has_sub_category
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

ajaxscripts.js:

```
$('.edit-category-button').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
 
    $.ajax({
            url: 'product-categories/fetchdata',
            method: 'get',
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#editcategory').modal('show');
                $('#category-name').val(data.name);
                if (data.subcategory === 'Yes') {
                    $('#sub_cat_yes').prop('checked', true);
                } else {
                    $('#sub_cat_no').prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        })
})
```

I'm getting this error.

> jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/product-categories/fetchdata?id=16 500 (Internal Server Error)

Log Error:

> show does not exist laravel

Not able to sort it. I'm going wrong somewhere.

Please let me know for any additional info.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: include your error log from `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @jewishmoses I've added. I got the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed after I edited my Routes file as:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('products.categories.index');
});

Route::get('product-categories/fetchdata', 'ProductCategoriesController@fetchdata')->name('category.fetchdata');
Route::resource('product-categories', 'ProductCategoriesController');
```

Basically, I just reordered the Routes.

Thank you

Comment: If you don't use certain actions you can exclude them: [Partial Resource Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes)